# MS Excel help needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am creating a monthly expense tracker for all my flatmates.

- The “Split between” has 4 options.
- A user will have to enter the items bought , enter the bought by(tag his name) and select the option in "Split between"

Split between has 4 conditions:

- if All 4 is selected the excel function will tag the divided price to the other members of the flat rather than who bought the item.ie it will add the divided value for eg suppose for a product bought by Subhajit the price is x and under split between  "All 4" is selected,the data that will be entered in each column except Subhajit will be x/4
- In case of the other option eg: Subhajit and Subhradeep and if the product is bought by Subhajit the price will be updated to Subhradeep’s column and vice versa.

[image: Image screenshot]

What function can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Nested IF function and a little bit long:

`=IF($E$2=$B4,"",IF($D4="All 4",$C4/4,IF(COUNTIF($D4,"*"&$E$2&"*")=1,IF($D4="Soham Subhajit and Subhradeep",$C4/3,IF($D4="Soham and Maiti",$C4/2,IF($D4="Subhajit and Subhradeep",$C4/2,""))),"")))`

In column B Bought by in B4 the first name
In column C Price in C4 the first price
In column D Split Between in D4 first split
In column E in E2 write Subhajit, in E4 the formula above
In column F in F2 write Soham, in F4 the formula modified (change $E$2 to $F$2)
In column G in G2 write Subhradeep, in G4 the formula modified (change $E$2 to $G$2)
In column H in H2 write Maiti, in H4 the formula modified (change $E$2 to $H$2)
After all the modification you can drag each formula down in the same column
whenever you write a new name, price and choose split between

Answer (score 0):

Two if statements and a requirement of keeping the AND between names.

```
Price   Split        A1         B1         C1         D1
125     All 4        $31.25      $31.25      $31.25      $31.25 
53      A1 and B1    $26.50      $26.50      $-          $-   
81      C1 D1 and B1 $-          $27.00      $27.00      $27.00
```

The formula checks for the word `All` at the beginning, and then divides the result by the number after the `All` (so if someone else joins, or someone leaves, just alter the number)
If it's not all, then it counts the number of spaces, and this gives it the number of people to divide between - As it uses the names above columns to check if they should be paying, it allows you to rename or add/remove columns and still have the formula work

I am assuming that the names are in row 1, and the price in C, split in D, and names start in E

Put this formula in E2, and copy to the other cells.

```
=IF(LEFT($D2,3)="All",$C2/VALUE(MID($D2,4,99)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(E$1,$D2)),0,$C2/(((LEN($D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D2," ","")))))))
```